# does Jsp runs under the Servlet code?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

if we write a code in jsp that will convert to servlet code and get runs. is it true? your suggestions are more thankful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/servlets_jsp/

> **How Do JSP Pages Work?**
>
> A JSP page is basically a web page
>   with traditional HTML and bits of Java
>   code. The file extension of a JSP page
>   is .jsp rather than .html or .htm,
>   which tells the server that this page
>   requires special handling that will be
>   accomplished by a server extension or
>   a plug-in.
>
> **When a JSP page is called, it will be compiled (by the JSP engine) into a
>   Java servlet**. At this point the
>   servlet is handled by the servlet
>   engine, just like any other servlet.
>   The servlet engine then loads the
>   servlet class (using a class loader)
>   and executes it to create dynamic HTML
>   to be sent to the browser, as shown in
>   Figure 1. The servlet creates any
>   necessary object, and writes any
>   object as a string to an output stream
>   to the browser.

[image]
<sub>(source: [sun.com](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javaserverpages/servlets_jsp/fig1.gif))</sub>

HTH